# Debugging a crash in a function from crash report

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My question is how to prevent this crash?

[Crash report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t52V.png)
I've a crash from live app on appstore which I can see in Organizer -> Crashes: App Store > Release
Clicking to open it leads me to this function

```
fetchClientBalance() { (result, error) in
    let (hour,min,secs) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: Int(durationInSecs)) // Crash here
}
```

Implementation of function is

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}

func fetchClientBalance(completed: @escaping ((_ result: Balance?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)) {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error in fetching balance")
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            completed(nil,error)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            completed(nil,error)
            return
        }

        do {
            let resultData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Balance.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed(resultData,nil)
                return
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            print("JSON Decoding Error")
            print(jsonError)
            completed(nil,jsonError)
            return
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Please include the full function for fetch. You have a callback that can't be seen. For example what is durationInSeconds? Where does it come from? Additionally, you should all the crash report or some explanation of what it says.

Comment: Tx. I've updated question with more details.

Comment: Your screenshot of the stack doesn't say what the error is. That's pretty important for understanding the crash. Was it a bad access? An assertion? Something else? Please post the text of a crashlog from ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/<appname>.

Comment: Crash happens on live app. How can I get log from live app users?

Comment: Your code example is clearly not accurate to the real world. In your top code block you don’t use `result` or `error`, and use a mysterious `durationInSecs` variable. Please make sure your question is complete before asking it. We can’t help you if you don’t paint the full picture.

Comment: durationInSecs is a float value. I've marked where error happens which is pretty much obvious without looking into entire file. Seems like durationInSecs value may be null or something. I'm not sure. I asked how to prevent this happening.

Comment: check durationInSeconds type. if that is milliseconds, then you are trying to convert that as Int. which may cause overflow and crash. if that is the case you can stick with int64 type.

Comment: durationInSeconds is of type float which represents seconds. Well the problem is that I've float values all along in the calculation to durationInSeconds. The value from API comes as string, I've to convert that string into Float then do some calculations to calculate durationInSeconds's value in float then convert it into Int. How to do it properly as not to crash it?